# Create a tab in eclipse ide project properties

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to create a tab with the existing tabs specifically in Project -> Properties -> C++ build -> Settings page.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can't add to an existing property page unless the plugin that provides the page defines an extension point to allow the page to be extended.

Comment: I know that org.eclipse.cdt.ui.cPropertyTab plays a vital role in adding the tab. But still unable to add the tab